# ImportError: cannot import name 'languages'

Tags: python, python-3.x, iso-639

I am trying to run a python script, but I get this error:

```
from iso639 import languages 
ImportError: cannot import name 'languages'
```

I have installed iso639, but I still get this error.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Was there something else I had to install?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 similarly named packages:

- `iso639` ([pip install from PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/iso639/), [source code at Github](https://github.com/janpipek/iso639-python))
- `iso-639` ([pip install from PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/iso-639/), [source code at Github](https://github.com/noumar/iso639))

You can check each package's PyPi and Github page to confirm which one you need.

But it seems what you are looking for is the `iso-639` package (with the hyphen). Because its [`__init.py__`](https://github.com/noumar/iso639/blob/master/iso639/__init__.py) file has an importable `languages` module:

```
"""
Python library for ISO 639 standard
Copyright (c) 2014-2016 Mikael Karlsson (CSC - IT Center for Science Ltd.).
Licensed under AGPLv3.
"""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from iso639.iso639 import Iso639

__version__ = '0.4.5'
languages = Iso639()
```

So make sure to install `iso-639`

```
$ python3 -m pip install iso-639
...
Installing collected packages: iso-639
Successfully installed iso-639-0.4.5
$ python3
...
>>> import iso639
>>> dir(iso639)
[... 'iso639', 'languages']
>>> from iso639 import languages
>>>
```

(Make sure to uninstall the other one, because both are imported as `from iso639`).

Comment: It could be a good idea to mention licenses for both packages - that is an important information for the choice. `iso-639` - `AGPLv3`, `iso639` - `MIT`.