# How to convert languages ISO639-1 codes to language names in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iso-639

I have the following Pandas series:

```
>>> df.original_language.value_counts()
en    32269
fr     2438
it     1529
ja     1350
de     1080
      ...  
la        1
jv        1
sm        1
gl        1
mt        1
Name: original_language, Length: 92, dtype: int64
4
```

I want to convert these language codes into their original names, for example

en >> English

ar >> Arabic

I looked up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773035/list-of-language-codes-iso639-1-in-python) but it didn't help.
If there are any packages required, please provide a source of how to install them using pip if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use iso-639 module ->

```
#pip install iso-639
from iso639 import languages
df['lang'] = df['lang'].apply(lambda x: languages.get(alpha2=x).name)
```

`output -`

```
       lang  count
0   English  32269
1    French   2438
2   Italian   1529
3  Japanese   1350
4    German   1080
5     Latin      1
6  Javanese      1
7    Samoan      1
8  Galician      1
9   Maltese      1
```

If you wanna convert codes in your original df, then use -

```
from iso639 import languages
df['original_language'] = df['original_language'].apply(lambda x: languages.get(alpha2=x).name)
```

Comment: Thank you!
The main problem for me was at installing, but turns out there are 2 modules with the same name, one with a hyphen and the other without. So this question helped me too solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58464166/importerror-cannot-import-name-languages

Comment: There's also iso639 package, is that something else? I'm using poetry and for some reason it couldn't find package iso-639 (even though pip could find it)